# Let $A_1,...,A_n\subset \mathbb R^d$. Find set together disjoint $B_1,...,B_N\subset \mathbb R^d$ such that $A_j=\bigcup_{i:B_i\subset A_j}B_i$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1,...,A_n\subset \mathbb R^d$. Find set together disjoint $B_1,...,B_N\subset \mathbb R^d$ such that
$$A_j=\bigcup_{i:B_i\subset A_j}B_i$$
for $j=1,...,n$ and $$\bigcup_{i}B_i=\bigcup_{j}A_j.$$

I absolutely don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

The sets $A_1\cap A_2$, $A_1\cap A_2^c$ and $A_1^c\cap A_2$ are disjoint. Doesn't this solve the case for $n=2$? Now expand this idea.